# github's graphql api contributionsCollection not pulling from sso organizations

Tags: github-api

I'm trying to bring back a users github contributions using the github graphql api, but it isn't including any contribution data from organizations that the user contributes to that requires SSO. I'm completely stumped on this because when I look at my public github page, and when I use third party tools like https://ghchart.rshah.org/jimeh87 the contributions do show up. Is there a different api I can use, or is there something I'm missing?

A simplified version of the query:

```
query {
  user(login: "jimeh87") {
    contributionsCollection {
      contributionCalendar {
        totalContributions
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For SSO enabled organization's you can't do that

Please refer this paragraph from [github docs](https://docs.github.com/en/account-and-profile/setting-up-and-managing-your-github-profile/managing-contribution-settings-on-your-profile/why-are-my-contributions-not-showing-up-on-my-profile):

If you are part of an organization that uses SAML single sign-on (SSO), you won’t be able to see contribution activity from the organization on your profile if you do not have an active SSO session. People viewing your profile from outside your organization will see anonymized contribution activity of your contribution activity for your organization.

Comment: The graph isn't returning anonymized contributions